# How to write connection string to other database in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there any way to make connection with other sql server database on different server from stored procedure?

I want to create a connection to a database which is on different server. I am already having one database on my sql server and I have written a procedure “SP_SelectRecords”.

I want to write sql statements in this same SP to update records in table which is on different server.
So is there any such a way?

OR

I have achieve this from my C# code?

Comment: [Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279(v=sql.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Linked Server for the other instance.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx

Comment: Is it possible in SQL Server 2005 OR 2008?

Comment: Yes, here's the 2005 page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Thank you so much. This one is also help. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35943/How-to-Config-Linked-Servers-in-a-Minute